# Error using XML package in R

Tags: r, xml-parsing, html-parsing, web-scraping

I am gathering data about different universities and I have a question about the follow error after executing the following code.  The problem is when using htmlParse()

Code:

url1 <- "http://nces.ed.gov/collegenavigator/?id=165015"

webpage1<- getURL(url1)

doc1 <- htmlParse(webpage1)

Output:

Error in htmlParse(webpage1) : File

!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"

html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" head id="ctl00_hd"meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" /title

```
    College Navigator - National Center for Education Statistics
```

/titlelink href="css/md0.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" meta name="keywords" content="college navigator,college search,postsecondary education,postsecondary statistics,NCES,IPEDS,college locator"/meta meta name="description" content="College Navigator is a free consumer information tool designed to help students, parents, high school counselors, and others get information about over 7,000 postsecondary institutions in the United States - such as programs offered, retention and graduation rates, prices, aid available, degrees awarded, campus safety, and accreditation."meta>meta name="robots" content="index,nofollow"/metalink

I have webs scraped pages before using this package and I never had an issue.  Does the name="robots" have anything to do with it?  Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fnces.ed.gov%2Fcollegenavigator%2F%3Fid%3D165015 
indicates the webpage is badly formed. Your browser can compensate for this but your R package is having problems.

if you are using windows you can get the IE browser to fix it for you as follows:

```
library(rcom)
library(XML)
ie = comCreateObject('InternetExplorer.Application')
ie[["visible"]]=T # true for debugging
comInvoke(ie,"Navigate2","http://nces.ed.gov/collegenavigator/?id=165015")
while(comGetProperty(ie,"busy")||comGetProperty(ie,"ReadyState")<4){
 Sys.sleep(1)
 print(comGetProperty(ie,"ReadyState"))
}
myDoc<-comGetProperty(ie,"Document")
webpage1<-myDoc$getElementsByTagName('html')[[0]][['innerHTML']]
ie$Quit()
doc1 <- htmlParse(webpage1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, your method allowed me to parse the page.  Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: One more quick question.  Do you know how to use this script with a different browser, say Firefox?  I tried replacing the Internet Explorer with Firefox and it didn't work.  Also sorry about not clicking the question as answered, just joined the site.