# Handling HTML web-scraping errors in R with XML package

Tags: r, xml-parsing, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a web page http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/on-135_metric_e.html like this one, and using the following code, I receive an error suggesting that the HTML is improper:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
weather <- getURL("http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/on-135_metric_e.html")
doc <- htmlParse(weather)
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956480/error-using-xml-package-in-r) post which demonstrates how to use Internet Explorer and the `rcom` package to fix improperly formed HTML and then feed it to the parser.  However the HTML in question passes the validation at http://validator.w3.org.

What other ways are there for handling an HTML parse-related error like this one with the XML package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a whirl and see if it does what you're after:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
url   <- "http://www.weatheroffice.gc.ca/city/pages/on-135_metric_e.html"
doc   <- htmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes=TRUE)
```

I also suggest you check out these resources:

1. [talkstats.com thread on web scraping (great beginner
   examples)](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/26153-Still-trying-to-learn-to-scrape)
2. [w3schools.com site on html stuff (very
   helpful)](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_nodes.asp)

Comment: Simple solution--so I was not actually experiencing an error, rather using the tool incorrectly.